# Using React Router v6 how can I create a redirect for a nested route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have some nested routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="components" element={<Components />}>
    <Route path="alert" element={<Alerts />} />
    <Route path="button" element={<Buttons />} />
    <Route path="chip" element={<Chips />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

I have an `<Outlet />` setup in `<Components>` and the nested routes work as expected.

```
/components/alert
/components/button
/components/chip
```

If someone visits `/components`, I would like to redirect them to `/components/alert`. Previously using v5 I would use a `<Redirect to="/components/alert">` component. How can I achieve this using v6?

I tried using the new `<Navigate>` component with a wildcard path like this:

```
<Route path="components" element={<Components />}>
  ...
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="alert" replace />} />
</Route>
```

But this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace from `Components` with `Alerts` you can use an `index` as

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="components" element={<Components />}>
    <Route index element={<Alerts />} />
    <Route path="alert" element={<Alerts />} />
    <Route path="button" element={<Buttons />} />
    <Route path="chip" element={<Chips />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

This would provide the `Alerts` component when `/components` is visited.

To redirect from  `/components` to `/components/alerts` whenever the former is visited you can use `Navigate` in that `index` as

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="components" element={<Components />}>
    <Route index element={<Navigate replace to="/components/alerts" />} />
    <Route path="alert" element={<Alerts />} />
    <Route path="button" element={<Buttons />} />
    <Route path="chip" element={<Chips />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: This works and I think using `index` is the way to go. I just needed to use `<Route index element={<Navigate replace to="alert" />} />` for the redirect, as the `components` part of the path is inherited. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For me, I am using the latest 6.4.2 and the redirection only works if I remove the element in the parent route like below.

  `<Route path="components">`
    `<Route index element={<Navigate replace to="alerts" />} />`

Answer (score 0):

With the details that you have provided, I can probably only think of one thing: is there any route conflicts? I think the problem with this is probably there.

I have created something similar to your code in Codesandbox and it worked fine for me.

My code as a reference (Codesandbox link may be deleted/dead in the future):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="components" element={<Components />}>
          <Route path="alert" element={<Another />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="alert" replace />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Components() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>

      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}

function Another() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Another Alert Component</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-butterfly-9k3vud?file=/src/App.js). I tried to navigate to `/components/123` and it instantly redirects to `/components/alert` for me. Perhaps the problem is with your configuration and/or the reverse proxy (if you're testing this in production)?

Comment: Going to `/components/123` does redirect me to `/components/alert` but I want to redirect `/components` when there is nothing following the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-golick-ozbwpd)

Navigate in the demo to /components. It will redirect you to `/components/alert`

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="components" element={<Components />}>
          <Route path="alert" element={<Another />} />
          <Route path="/components" element={<Navigate to="/components/alert" replace />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```